Referencing swappable ability system in unity / C#
So I am trying to make a swappable ability system in unity with a main ability class and each ability inheriting from it to do its unique effect. Im struggling with being able to apply the abilities to the player once they have selected them.
Currently the main ability code is:
        public abstract class Ability : MonoBehaviour
        {
            public int id = -1;
            public string abilityName = string.Empty;
            public string description = string.Empty;

            enum AbilityState { Ready, Casting, Cooldown}
            AbilityState state = AbilityState.Ready;

            public float cooldown = 0f;

            public bool castDone = false;

            public bool castIFrames = false;
            public bool castLockMove = false;

            public void TryCast() 
            {
                if (state == AbilityState.Ready)
                {
                    StartCoroutine(Cast());
                    StartCoroutine(UseAbility());
                }
            }

            IEnumerator Cast()
            {
                state = AbilityState.Casting;
                if (castLockMove) 
                {
                    //disable movement    
                }
                if (castIFrames)
                {
                    //disbale hit collider
                }
                yield return new WaitUntil(() => castDone = true);
                //make sure things are back on
                StartCoroutine(CooldDown());
            }

            IEnumerator CooldDown()
            {
                state = AbilityState.Cooldown;
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(cooldown);
                state = AbilityState.Ready;
            }

            public abstract IEnumerator UseAbility();

            public void RemoveThis()
            {
                Destroy(this);
            }
        }

With a specific implantation like this:
        public Test_Dash()
        {
            id = 1;
            abilityName = "Dash";
            description = "Quick move forwards";
            cooldown = 4f;
            castIFrames = true;
        }

        float dashFactor;
        Vector2 direction;

        public override IEnumerator UseAbility()
        {
            castDone = false;
            yield return null;
            while (PlayerClass.playerObject.GetComponent<PlayerAndCamera>().moveInfo != Vector2.zero)
            {
                yield return null;
            }
            direction = PlayerClass.playerObject.GetComponent<PlayerAndCamera>().moveInfo;
            StartCoroutine(Dash());
        }

        IEnumerator Dash()
        {
            PlayerClass.playerObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(direction * dashFactor * 0.3f);
            yield return null;
            PlayerClass.playerObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(direction * dashFactor * 0.9f);
            yield return null;
            PlayerClass.playerObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(direction * dashFactor * 1f);
            castDone = true;
        }
    }

Then I need to apply an ability to the player:
    public class Abilities
    {
        public Ability abl1;
        public Ability abl2;
        public Ability abl3;
        public Ability abl4;
    }

Is there another method to do this without making an individual game object for each ability or one game object with all the ability on it as both of those methods seem very clunky and can easily get out of hand. Sorry for all the code block just trying to make my question and context as clear as possible.

You should have the Player have a List or a Dictionary<X,Ability> where X is something that identifies the ability (like a string-- abilityName).

Or have IAbility, and it has a method of say "Perform" and that perform does whatever the ability is, and any class which has interface is now able to be used and called

You could use ScriptableObject instead of MonoBehaviour so these are actual assets you can modify and throw into a list without needing GameObjects for them

@BugFinder whether you use an interface or - like OP - an abstract base class in this regard makes little difference - except that the base class already brings some common implementation (+ serializing interfaces in Unity Inspector is always weird)

Btw if Dash is still supposed to be part of the UseAbility meaning it should wait for it you should rather do yield return Dash(); .. and in general you should cache references instead of multiple GetComponent calls
